# Adding key/value pair to appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core Web App using Stripe.net Checkout

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, stripe.net

When I create a new ASP.NET Core Web App project and run it, it builds and runs fine. However, when I add a Stripe key/value pair to the appsettings.json file and run again, the code stops at

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

and I get an error. The error starts at WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder: the whole body of the BuildWebHost method is highlighted in green: error CS0119: 'WebHost' is a type, which is not valid in the given context. It does not throw an exception directly. Removing the "Stripe" section in appsettings.json fixes it and everything works fine then.

I am trying to implement Stripe.net Checkout (https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/aspnet)

I am adding secret key and publishable key key/value pairs to the appsettings.json file. Does anyone know how to solve this? Maybe define

```
"Stripe": { "SecretKey": "sk_test", "PublishableKey": "pk_test" }
```

in a separate .json file? If so, how to read from it instead of using

```
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")[SecretKey]);
```

Thank you.

Comment: So what exactly is the error you have?

Comment: The error starts at WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder: the whole body of the BuildWebHost method is highlighted in green: error CS0119: 'WebHost' is a type, which is not valid in the given context. It does not throw an exception directly. Removing the "Stripe" section in appsettings.json fixes it and everything works fine then.

Comment: please update your question instead of adding comment

Comment: Question updated.